# Need to create code words to remember important years (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need a way to create code words to remember important years in history.
Suppose we have the following sentence "In **1929** the Congress Session was held at Lahore under the Presidentship of Pt. Jawaharlal Nehru". The year 1929 should be represented in the following way: 
1 - A
9 - LahorCong
2 - Pt
9 - President
i.e., the number of alphabets in the code should match the number represented, while making sense of the information to be recollected.

Could someone help me with the algorithm

Comment: I have tried removing the vowels, but don't know how to merge words like in the example to get the exact number of letters.

Comment: what is the purpose of creating an algorithm like this? to memorize the sentences?

Comment: No. The purpose is to memorize important years in history